# Copy the value in cell 1 multiple times the given number in cell 2

Tags: excel

I was searching but found no specific answer to my question. 
How can I automatically copy values in

> "B1" to next cells in same row, times the amount given in "A1".

So if (e.g.) cell A1's value is "4", then copy B1 4 times in next cells, as in C1 to F1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no VBA tag so I'm guessing you want a formula solution.

In cell C1 use this formula:

```
=IF(COLUMN()-2>$A1,"",$A1)
```

Then copy it down the column the length of your data, and copy right as far as the maximum number in column A.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Allthough, I'm a little slow on formulas, can you explain the logical_test from IF function?

Comment: Logical test: If the (current column number - 2) > the (number in column A in the same row) Then (blank output "") Else (Return column A value).  The reason you want column number - 2 is because the formula starts in column C, which is the 3rd column.  So at column C it would be If (3-2) > (number in column A).  If the number in column A is 4 like in your question, then for column C (the first cell the formula is in) the check becomes: If (3-2=1)>4 (False, return column A value). For the column D: If (4-2=2)>4 (False, return column A value.) ... For column G: If (7-2=5)>4 (True, return blank)